# Jest - Cannot generate cobertura coverage report for my projects

Tags: jestjs, cobertura

I'm using `jest` in a monorepo. I would like to generate a Cobertura report when testing a some of my projects.

#### Jest.config.base.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  transform: {
    'vee-validate/dist/rules': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/*.(spec|test).(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    // Allow test environment to fire onload event
    // See https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-355188615
    resources: 'usable',
  },
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      'jest-trx-results-processor',
      {
        outputFile: './coverage/test-results.trx',
        defaultUserName: 'user name to use if automatic detection fails',
      },
    ],
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'ts',
    'json',
    'vue',
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue',
  ],
  runner: 'groups',
};
```

#### Jest.config (root)

```
const baseConfig = require('./jest.config.base')

module.exports = {
  ...baseConfig,
  projects: [
    '<rootDir>/apps/my-app',
    '<rootDir>/apps/my-app-copy',
    '<rootDir>/libs/my-lib',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage/',
};
```

#### Jest.config (my-app)

```
const baseConfig = require('../../jest.config.base');
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  ...baseConfig,
  transformIgnorePatterns: [],
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src',
  ],
  name: packageJson.name,
  displayName: packageJson.name,
};
```

I did not paste other jest.config to save space, but they are similar.

## What works

If I run `jest --coverage --coverageReporters=cobertura`, it will generate a Cobertura report, but all my projects will be tested.

## What does not work

If I run `jest --projects apps/my-app apps/my-app-copy --coverage --coverageReporters=cobertura`, only `test-results.trx` is generated.

### Question

How could I test only 2 projects out of 3, and generate a single Cobertura report for those?

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on something similar in our monorepo and I was able to generate the cobertura report installing `jest-junit` and defining the reporters in the root jest.config like this

```
coverageReporters: ['html', 'text', 'text-summary', 'cobertura'],
```

Then I run `jest --coverage`

Comment: The docs for configuring Jest are here: https://archive.jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration